# How do I use getOptions to retrieve the truesize array values in Jcrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

How do I use getOptions to retrieve the truesize array values in Jcrop?

I can use setOptions no problem

```
api.setOptions({trueSize: [w, h]});
```

Found something about it in the link below but still cant figure out how to use it.
https://github.com/nathanaeljones/Jcrop/commit/714c2d86983f587c1c7e6203a88fb0dc8bf03cd7

Answer (score 2):

The getOptions() function returns options as an object so you need to access it as given below

```
  jcrop_api.getOptions().boxWidth
  jcrop_api.getOptions().maxSize
```